# Как обратиться к #include ".." уровнем выше?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Наверно, я туплю. У меня есть файл `"stdafx.h"`, который `Visual Studio` создает сама. Рядом с этим файлом есть файл `myFile.cpp`, в котором я пишу `#include "stdafx.h"`, и ошибок нет. У меня есть папка `Qwerty`, в которой есть файл `qwe.cpp`. В файле `qwe.cpp` я пишу `#include "stdafx.h"`, и мне вываливается ошибка - такого файла не существует. Конечно, не существует, ведь файл `"stdafx.h"` находится в папке уровнем выше, а не в папке `Qwerty`. Как мне к нему обратиться?
Примерно так выглядит все дерево:

```
(папка) MyProject
  stdafx.h
  myFile.cpp
  (папка) Qwerty
    qwe.cpp
```

И мне нужно из файла `qwe.cpp` обратиться к файлу `MyProject\stdafx.h`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#include"../stdafx.h"`. Ну и так для любого похожего случая, каждый ../ - это один уровень вверх.